# What's the difference between "where does he go" and "where is he going"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

I want to know the difference between this two and the usage of these two like where we use these basically

Comment: Could you show us why you’re confused and to what extent? Have you looked up any of the grammar involved? What do you know about tenses?

Answer (score 2):

"He is going [somewhere]" means that he is on his way there, or intending to go, so "Where is he going?" = "What place is he on his way to?"

"He goes [somewhere]" means that he is in the habit of going there.

"Where does he go to school?"
"Where does he go for his art materials?" = "Where does he usually buy them?"